# Array in for cycle not getting proper values

Tags: c, arrays, linux, for-loop, pointers

My problem:

I have a struct of an item and a bag;

```
struct Item {
    int value;
    int weight;
};

struct Bag {
    int maxWeight;
    Item *items;
    int maxItems;
    int itemsHolding;
};
```

In my main I've got this array:

```
 int testValues[] = { 4, 11, 6, 2, 10, 4, 12, 6, 13, 7, 23 };
```

- index 0: total number of items
- index 1: total weight of the bag
- last index: ignore it for this problem
- all other indexes are a "pair"

For example:

- 6 will represent the first item value
- 2 will represent the first item weight
- and so on

Then I have this array of Items

```
Item items[testValues[0]];
```

And this function that should organize all values into the correspondent item:

```
void item_InitUsableItems(int *values, int nItems, Item *items) {
    for (int i = 2; i < nItems + 2; i+=2) {
        items[i-2].value = values[i];
        items[i-2].weight = values[i+1];
    }
}
```

Call to function:

```
item_InitUsableItems(testValues, testValues[0], items);
```

I'm then printing all items to the console just for testing purposes:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
    printf("%d - %d\n", items[i].value, items[i].weight);
}
```

This is giving me results like:

```
6 - 2
-1231927808 - -1282274509
10 - 4
1666274963 - 22033
```

Expected result would be this:

```
6 - 2
10 - 4
12 - 6
13 - 7
```

I'm new to C, about a week into learning it! If you spot anything else that's incorrect please let me know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void item_InitUsableItems(int *values, int nItems, Item *items) {
int j = 2;
for (int i = 0; i < nItems; i++) {
    items[i].value = values[j];
    j++;
    items[i].weight = values[j];
    j++;
}
```

}

This solved my problem. Probably not the prettiest solution but it works!

Comment: See if you can calculate `j` based on `i`. Then you don't need `j`.

Answer (score 2):

```
for (int i = 2; i < nItems + 2; i+=2) {
    items[i].value = values[i];
    items[i].weight = values[i+1];
}
```

The loop initializes `item[2]` through `item[5]`. It should initialize `item[0]` through `item[3]`.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
    printf("%d - %d\n", items[i].value, items[i+1].weight);
}
```

Why `i` and `i+1`? Those indices should be the same so the value and weight are from the same item.